# limits of a strange function

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\[2ex]
-x^2 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$$

Find the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to a$ (where $a$ is any real number) by sequential characterization of limits.

I have tried: given any $a$, a real number, and $n$ a natural number, then by Archimedean property showing that there exists a rational number $r_n$ not equal to $a$, and $a-\frac 1n<r_n<a+\frac 1n$ and an irrational $S_n$, with $S_n$ not equal $a$ and $a-\frac 1n<S_n<a+\frac 1n$. In particular, $\lim r_n=a=\lim S_n$ as $n \to \infty$.

I then tried to find $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(r_n)$ , and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(s_n)$, but I can not go any further

Comment: Using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in the reals and the definition of limit you should be able to prove that the limit is 0 if $a=0$ and doesn't exist otherwise.

Comment: This is an interesting function as it is differentiable in only one point.

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check that I didn't introduce any errors.